# Cat motion detector that can tell the difference from humans

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to build a cat motion detector but, to avoid getting false alarms when a person walks by, I was thinking of using RFID. i.e. the cat has a collar and the detector senses the collar when they get within a couple of feet and makes a noise.

The problem there seems to be with RFID is that the range is so short - e.g. 4".

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Where do you want to use it? Do you want detect when it goes though an door/corridor? More information would be helpful, as there is different kinds of motion detection. E.g. laser-tripwire, which you could place at different height similar to what  Dave X describes.

Answer (score 1):

Place an additional motion sensor such that it can only detect motion from things significantly taller than cats, and use that as an inhibitor/classifier of the cat motion signal.

Answer (score 0):

What about a transmitter on the collar - Bluetooth, or a coded infra red pulse, that could be detected by fixed stations?

Battery life and safety (swallowing batteries!) would be serious considerations though...